# Excel Averageifs with both AND and OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to get the average of a column if some nested AND / OR conditions are met:

=AVERAGEIFS (Target_Col,(Col_A >= Date1 AND Col_B <= Date2 ) OR (Col_A >= Date3 AND Col_B <= Date4)

Is there a way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Could you post a data example and expected output? AVERAGEIFS can handle several argument but each argument is a single condition, so putting 2 or more conditions work as an AND operator, unless you work with arrays formulation, that would be equivalent to OR operations

Comment: You'll need a `SUM(SUMIFS())/SUM(COUNTIFS())` construction. For example: `=SUM(SUMIFS(Target_Col,Col_A,">="&G3:G4,Col_B,"<="&H3:H4))/SUM(COUNTIFS(Col_A,">="&G3:G4,Col_B,"<="&H3:H4))` where G3:G4 have the 'from' dates and H3:H4 have the 'to' dates.

Comment: @Rory 's solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to handle this situation is to create a "helper" column in your workbook that contains the AND/OR functions, and then create an average of that column.

Example:

New column contains the formula
IF(OR(AND(ColA >= Date1, ColB <=Date2), AND(ColA >= Date3, ColB <= Date4)),TargetCol,"")

This will return the value to average if conditions are met, or a blank if no conditions are met. Then simply take an average of your "helper" column.